# What is size of NUMBER and CURRENCY types in crystal reports?

Tags: types, crystal-reports-2008

What is size of "NUMBER" and "CURRENCY" types in crystal reports?
for example size of "int" type in c# = -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647          .....TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. "NUMBER" type in crystal reports 2008 can has only 15 digits; more than 15 digits, it be overflow and show wrong.